# How can I make a intranet server and external web server in one server computer.

Tags: networking, web, vmware, intranet

First of all, if there already been this kinda question, I want to apologize. I couldn't find

what I am trying to do is this.

1. make a intranet and allow embedded computer to connect with wifi
2. make a web server that is connected to internet on same computer with a intranet.
3. let a smart phone can get a data from intranet by an application that is accessed to web server.

do I need two network card? or is there any other solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the physical host connected to the internet using WiFi?

In the case if you want to have your web server and your intranet as a VMs

- Firstly you can create a virtual network on your physical host which is internet facing (gives access to internet) - bridged adapter to the physical (host) NIC (aka adapter) (ethernet / wireless)
- Secondly you can create non-internet facing network which will be your "intranet" network which will not be internet facing.

Then if you want to give your VMs access to the internet and intranet you can add two virtual NICs to each VM.

I hope that helps :)